# getting the value of an object node - javascript

Tags: javascript

newbie here .. wondering why in the table i get something called '[object node]' and not the actual value?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = wonfunction;


if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","sc2xml.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;



function wonfunction() {

        var homestead = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("sc2cash");

        document.getElementById('num1').innerHTML = homestead[0];
}
        </script>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<table width="200" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>Players</td>
    <td id="num1"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
```

Comment: ah yes, i figured it out.. .textContent was what I was looking for.. but was wondering how to get it to work in IE??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your comment:

In IE8 atleast you can use the `.text` property of a node like so:

```
var myNodes = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('node');
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = myNodes[0].text;
```

Some good articles are [alistapart AJAX](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/gettingstartedwithajax) and a [MS blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jscript/archive/2008/04/01/reading-xml-file-with-jscript.aspx) with some good examples too.

[Here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fYUAN/) that works fine in IE8.